# Show that among the numbers $y_1, . . . , y_n$, there is a number which greater than or equal to average $z =\frac{y_1\:+\:.\:.\:.\:+\:y_n}{n}$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing

**My solution:**

Proof by contradiction:

Assume there does not exist any number between $y_1, . . . , y_n$ which is greater than or equal to ($\ge$) $z$.

Then, we can say that $y_1 < z$, $y_2 < z$, $y_3 < z$, . . . , $y_n <z$

This implies: $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + . . . + y_n < n \cdot  z$

$\rightarrow$ $\frac{y_1\:+\:y_2\:+\:y_3\:+\:.\:.\:.\:+\:y_n}{n}<z$

But this is not possible because $\frac{y_1\:+\:y_2\:+\:y_3\:+\:.\:.\:.\:+\:y_n}{n} = z$, hence, a contradiction.

Therefore, there has to be a number between $y_1, . . . , y_n$ which is greater than or equal to ($\ge$) $z$.

**I don't know if this is right or not, if someone can provide some feedback that would be amazing!**

Comment: Seems completely fine to me.

Comment: Have a little confidence, Yaya!

Comment: Looks good! ${}{}$